# django server is showing no result

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I started working on django ( read the django documentation and several youtube tutorials )
I dont understand what is wrong , the editor is not showing any errors ( VSCode ).
When I start the server it is showing me the default rocket icon ....I have tried reinstalling django but it also didnt help....also restarted the server several times.
I am stuck right now.
[image]
[image]

***main url file***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('calc/',include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**url file for the app (calc)**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index')
]
```

**views file for the app**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World")
```

Comment: You don't have function named as **index** in your calc.views.py, right? You should update it as views.home IMO

Answer (score 2):

edit url path in calc app to the below. 
path('', views.home ,name='index')